# How to convert a flat list into a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a flat list containing information of multiple variables and need to convert it into a dictionary. For example, 'a','b','c' are variable names and need to be the keys in the dictionary. The list could be split by '_' and ':'.

```
list_x = ['a:1_b:45_c:abc','a:2_b:24_c:def','a:4_b:78_c:xxx']
```

The desired output would be:

```
dict_x = {'a':[1,2,4],'b':[45,24,78],'c':['abc','def','xxx']}
```

I am not sure how to loop to get the keys for the dictionary since it is the same for all elements in the list.

Comment: this is lots of job! what did u tried so far?

Comment: just to confirm, you want the list of strings as a dict with keys and values as a list? Also, the values need to be ints where it's possible and string where it's not? If yes, please check my solution and if it solves what you need .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that your dictionary is dictionary of type string: list that is why I check if the dictionary contains the key and if it does then I push the item and if it doesn't then add a new key with a list containing only the value.

```
list_x = ['a:1_b:45_c:abc','a:2_b:24_c:def','a:4_b:78_c:xxx']
print(list_x)

dic_x = dict()

for x in list_x:
    keyValueList = x.split('_')
    for keyValue in keyValueList:
        split = keyValue.split(':')
        key = split[0]
        value = split[1]
        if key in dic_x:
            dic_x[key].append(value)
        else:
            dic_x.update({key: [value]})

print(dic_x)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list_x = ['a:1_b:45_c:abc','a:2_b:24_c:def','a:4_b:78_c:xxx']

result_dict = {}

for list_element in list_x:
    key_val_pair = list_element.split('_')

    for key_val in key_val_pair:
        key, val = key_val.split(':')

        if key not in result_dict:
            result_dict[key] = []

        result_dict[key].append(val)

print(result_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [y.split(":") for x in [x.split("_") for x in list_x] for y in x]
d = {x:[] for x in set([x[0] for x in lst])}
for k, v in lst:
    d[k].append(v)
# Out[40]: {'a': ['1', '2', '4'], 'c': ['abc', 'def', 'xxx'], 'b': ['45', '24', '78']}
```

Comment: @ponderwonder if it was helpful, can you select the answer as accepted answer, to help future readers?

Answer (score 2):

Try this method (explanation inline as code comments) -

```
#Function to turn a list of tuples into a dict after converting integers and keeping string types.
def convert(tup):
    di = {}
    for a, b in tup:
        if b.isdecimal(): #convert to int if possible
            b = int(b)
        di.setdefault(a, []).append(b) 
    return di 

#convert the input into a list of tuples
k = [tuple(j.split(':')) for i in list_x for j in i.split('_')]

#convert list of tuples into dict
convert(k)
```

```
{'a': [1, 2, 4], 'b': [45, 24, 78], 'c': ['abc', 'def', 'xxx']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming strings in your list_x always have the same format as: `a:integer_b:integer_c:string`, you can do this:

```py
dict_x = {'a':[],'b':[],'c':[]}
for s in list_x:
    sl = s.split('_')
    dict_x['a'].append(int(sl[0][2:]))
    dict_x['b'].append(int(sl[1][2:]))
    dict_x['c'].append(sl[2][2:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can solve you problem with an easy way without being too much verbose neither compact. It's versatile so you can add as much identifier as you want but as you can see the format of them should be the same

```
list_x = ['a:1_b:45_c:abc','a:2_b:24_c:def','a:4_b:78_c:xxx']
dict_x ={}

for val in list_x:
  elements = val.split('_')
  for el in elements:
    key, value = el.split(':')[0], el.split(':')[1]
    if dict_x.get(key) is None:  #If the key it's founded for the first time
      dict_x[key] = [value]
    else:                        #If I've already founded the key the data is being appended
      dict_x[key].append(value)
print(dict_x)
```

As you can see the core it's the **if** that checks if the key founded not exists, in this case create a new array containing the first value founded; otherwise append the value to the actual array.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please check it as a solution so any user can use it in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First split each string based on `_` as delimiter and then split it based on `:` as delimiter, and add each item to a dict

```
>>> list_x = ['a:1_b:45_c:abc','a:2_b:24_c:def','a:4_b:78_c:xxx']
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for s in list_x:
...     for kv in s.split('_'):
...         k,v = kv.split(':')
...         d[k].append(int(v) if v.isdigit() else v)
... 
>>> dict(d)
{'a': [1, 2, 4], 'b': [45, 24, 78], 'c': ['abc', 'def', 'xxx']}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's split the string by ':' and then '_'

```
list_x = ['a:1_b:45_c:abc','a:2_b:24_c:def','a:4_b:78_c:xxx']

def parse(s):
    return [t.split(":") for t in s.split("_")]

parsed_to_lists = [parse(st) for st in list_x]
```

We now have

```
[[['a', '1'], ['b', '45'], ['c', 'abc']], [['a', '2'], ['b', '24'], ['c', 'def']], [['a', '4'], ['b', '78'], ['c', 'xxx']]]
```

we can flatten that by

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in parsed_to_lists for item in sublist]

flat_list
```

Which returns

```
[['a', '1'], ['b', '45'], ['c', 'abc'], ['a', '2'], ['b', '24'], ['c', 'def'], ['a', '4'], ['b', '78'], ['c', 'xxx']]
```

We want the result as a dictionary of lists, so let's create an empty one

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
```

and fill it

```
for k,v in flat_list:
    res[k].append(v)

res

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['1', '2', '4'], 'b': ['45', '24', '78'], 'c': ['abc', 'def', 'xxx']})
```